# Listview.builder widget does not render in column widget

Tags: flutter

The listview.builder widget fails to display the commentCard widget when The class containing the listview.builder code is called in a column widget of another class. When the listview.builder widget is called with the comment card widget, i get almost the same result.

This is my code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
   return  ListView.builder(
       //shrinkWrap: true,
       controller: _scrollController,
       itemCount: _numComments,
       itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
         //final comment = comments[index];

         return Expanded(
           child: CommentCard(
             snap: comments[index],
             document: widget.document,
             user: widget.username,
             focus: widget.focusNode,
           ),
         );
       },
     );
      
  }
```

I wrapped the commentCard and Listview.builder widgets in exapnded and even flexible widgets.
I used sizeBox widget to wrap commentCard but the height is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` and try to follow this pattern

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
       controller: _scrollController,
       itemCount: _numComments,
       itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
         //final comment = comments[index];
         return CommentCard(
```

You can check [Unbounded height / width | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI&vl=en)

Comment: I tried that previously but it didn't work.

Comment: can you include your `CommentCard` or try  provide a fixed height with `SizedBox` on top of it. Btw, are  you putting this widget inside Column as the title

Comment: i tried all of those but i almost the same error and the listview.builder continues to not render

Comment: can you create a sample widget from scaffold that will reproduce the same error and include on question

Comment: In the class where the listview.builder was referenced  in another class, this is a part of the code: Column(

                                              children: [



                                                CommentList(document: document, focusNode: focusNode, username: username,),
]);

Comment: what is the parent of `Column`

Comment: it is the body of a scaffold widget.

Comment: perhaps the error is occurring from your `CommentCard`, try to replace it with Text widget.

Comment: The comment card is what shows the author of the comment, comment details(text), date of the comment and the ability to like/dislike the comment wrapped in the commentCard widget.

Comment: I was thinking the error is possibly from that side. The parent widget in the comment card is a column widget. Inside that column widget i use flexible and expanded widgets to wrap other widgets where the size of them may be unpredicatble